# declare local repository in gradle build

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am migrating from Eclipse & maven to Android Studio & Gradle build.

My project structure now in Android Studio looks like this:

```
MyApp
 ->LibModule
   -src
   -...
   -lib_repo/
   -build.gradle
 ->AnotherModule
   ...
```

I have two questions:

**Q1.** in **build.gradle** of `LibModule`, is there a default variable which points to the root path of `LibModule`, I mean the path `MyApp/LibModule/`. For exapmle, in Eclipse, in pom.xml I could specify the root of `LibModule` **project** as :

```
<url>file://${project.basedir}</url>
```

what is the counterpart in gradle?

**Q2.** the `lib_repo` under `LibModule` is my local maven repository, in Eclipse (pom.xml) I could declare it as :

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>lib-repo</id>
        <url>file://${project.basedir}/lib_repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

In **gradle** build , how can I declare the same thing? I know I need to do something like:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "what should be here"
    }
}
```

but I am not sure what is the url I should declare in gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:** Yes, it's `project.projectDir`.

**Question 2:** Any valid URI, in this case `"file://${project.projectDir}/lib_repo"`.

Comment: Where is the place ${project.projectDir} has been defined/declared?

Comment: By default it is the folder where your build.gradle is located.

Comment: when anyone needs the path to root project, see example: `allprojects { buildDir = "${rootProject.rootDir}/.build/${project.name}" }`